# How to test a scenario that requires javascript to complete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, integration-testing, rspec2, factory-bot

A project I'm working on fetches data from a 3rd party service and caches it locally along with specific info for my app.

**My environment:**

- I provide a search mechanism against the service's search API.
- When a user browses to the item page for the first time, the my server fetches the info from the service and stores it
- On subsequent requests the browser just requests the information from my server

.. **however**.. I want info from the 3rd party service to stay up to date.

**My plan (feedback welcome!)**

- On a subsequent request after page load, some JS will ping the 3rd party service to check for updates
- If the item has been updated, push an update to my copy server side

**How to test this?**

When I write a controller spec I don't think the page's javascript is executed (to fetch the since-updated item from the service)

I had quite a bit of trouble trying to describe this so a diagram might help.

[image]

Technology I'm using: Rails/RSpec/Factory Girl/JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are a few ways to test this assuming my current solution.

Thoughtbot makes a library called capybara-webkit that will spin up webkit in the background and render/run your tests through it. Selenium is another.

[github link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit)

[blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/10314620132/modern-applications-use-javascript-you-can-make)

back on this project after a bit of a hiatus.. using capybara and :js => true seems to work - some tricky timing issues, but otherwise good to go

Answer (score 0):

Let's think out of the box a little to solve this.

Can you hit the 3rd Party Service from the Back End when the page is requested? Then you remove the dependance on JavaScript.

There are a few other methods that are better than this, like putting the "update item information" action into a queue, and then processing it in the background on the Back End. This would allow for the 3rd Party Service to not slow your site down.

Comment: thanks for the response!

I could request an update from the service on every request, but I'd prefer not to because I'd like the user who requested the info to get it refreshed